# Java generics: Unbounded wildcard is not working with Object type argument

Tags: java, generics

Explaining the issue with an example:

```
public class DataWrapper<T> {
    T data;
};

DataWrapper<Object> obj1 = new DataWrapper<Object>();

List<DataWrapper<?>> anyDataList = Arrays.asList(obj1); //this doesn't work

DataWrapper<Integer> objInt = new DataWrapper<Integer>();
anyDataList = Arrays.asList(obj1, objInt); //this work
```

I couldn't understand why "Arrays.asList(obj1)" doesn't work?

Comment: Upgrade to Java 8 for better results :)

Comment: The Java Type system is pretty difficult to code around without an IDE, that's for sure.

Comment: Confirmed: This works in Java 8

Answer (score 9):

Java 7 was stupid (not it wasn't) when inferring type arguments for generic methods. For example, it would use the declared type of an argument to infer the type regardless of the context of the method invocation. So in

```
Arrays.asList(obj1);
```

the type argument would be inferred as

```
DataWrapper<Object>
```

the method's return type would then be `List<DataWrapper<Object>>` which is no assignable to a `List<DataWrapper<?>>`.

In

```
Arrays.asList(obj1, objInt);
```

the type is inferred from both arguments. A common type is found between the two. In this case, that's `? extends Object`. The method return type becomes `List<DataWrapper<? extends Object>>` which is assignable to `List<DataWrapper<?>>`.

In Java 8, what you posted works out of the box. In Java 7, you can provide an explicit type argument to make it work

```
List<DataWrapper<?>> anyDataList = Arrays.<DataWrapper<?>>asList(obj1);
```

Comment: +1 for the explanation. Can you also provide a workaround for people using Java 7?

Comment: DataWrapper<Integer> can be assigned to DataWrapper<?>. Extending this logic, I expected the wildcard to work for second level nested type parameters also: List<DataWrapper<Object>> should be assignable to List<DataWrapper<?>>

Comment: @user1447561 Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p). It's not immediately obvious that they aren't.